# apache redirect to https for particular port number

Tags: node.js, apache, http, https, centos

I am running two nodejs sites on different port number like,

```
example.com:2001 &  example.com:2002
```

I need to redirect to https for only one port number like

If user enter `http://example.com:2001`
it should redirect to `https://example.com:2001` only for this port number.

Please tell me how to do with apache.

I am using apache web server with centos.

Comment: Are you running apache and node on the same box?

Comment: @dusan.bajic, what do you mean by same box ?

Comment: it will be hard, if you have an https server listenin on port 2001 the http dialog on this port will fail early, I do not know a way to redirect a user after a failure to talk `https` on an `https` port  (this is why usually you have prt 80 and 443 by default)

Comment: @regilero, I have update question with real urls, I am creating https connection from nodejs application. Please advise now.

Comment: created https server in app.js, example.com:2001 working now. Thanks – Laxman More Nov 22 '15 at 13:57